# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes when running `systemctl restart systemd-logind.service`

Tags: 18.04, suspend, power-management, bug-reporting, lid

I am trying to change my laptop's lid close behavior following this article: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/

When I get to run:

```
systemctl restart systemd-logind.service
```

my system freezes and gets stuck.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Restarting `systemd-logind` is not good for your graphical session(s).  I would have expected the session to crash and log you out instead, but that's not what they imply either. I have no idea what they were doing. I would suggest rebooting instead of running the restart command.

In case you set it to hibernate, make sure that you have also tested hibernation, e.g. by running this command:

```
systemctl hibernate
```